# Measure theory: Evaluating a real-valued function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I do not seem to understand how to evaluate/compute a real valued function when integrating with respect to a measure (e.g. Lebesgue measure). I get confused which definition of integral to use.

What I understand:

I know the theory that we begin with simple functions and we extend that to the following definition of the integral for real valued functions.

$\int f d\mu:= \int f^{+} d\mu - \int f^{-} d \mu$ where $f^{+}(x):= f(x), x \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise, similarly $f^{-}(x):= -f(x), x < 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

I also know the following result (amongst others):

1. $\int_{E}f d\mu = \int \chi_{E}f d\mu$
2. $\int \chi_{E} d \mu = \mu(E)$

Would I be correct that in the above I can rewrite 1. as $f  \mu(E)$?

Simple example I will try to solve:

Let $f(x) = 1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $-1$ for $x < 0$. I want to calculate $\int f d\mu$ over the real line where $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{+}d \mu - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{-} d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1 d\mu - \int_{\mathbb{R}} -1 d\mu$

from here I then get a bit stuck, do I now rewrite it as $1$ times an indicator function or something??

Thoughts added later:

Since the Lebesgue integral will give the same value as the Riemann integral, I know that the answer should give infinity. If I was just integrating this with respect to $x$ I know how to compute it. But I don't know how to proceed in the Lebesgue case (as above).

Comment: You are playing with a function where each part has infinite integral.  Bad idea.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes perhaps not the best choice. Given Riemann and Lebesgue will give the same answer I know the answer must be infinity. But I don't know how we proceed from the step I am on when computing the integral as a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Your last line has errors.  Should be $\int_{R^+}1d\mu=\int_R \chi_E 1d\mu$ etc.  $E=R^+$